# Access to localhost from android emulator

Tags: android, .net, api, android-emulator, localhost

I am trying to connect to my API from an emulator. API is simple, GET method returns a date. Now the API is deployed on the local IIS at the address **https://localhost:4433/api/echo**. As you can see, it is in order. Now I need to connect to this URL from the emulator. However, I get a mistake **Invalid Hostname**. Emulator Pixel 5- API 30.

[image]

**UPD**

If I try access my api via IP instead of `localhost` I get `Invalid Hostname` responce. Exactly as request from emulator.

[image]

Site bindings at IIS.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried in a browser on the computer to access via it's IP address not via localhost hostname? As this is a server error have you only bound IIS to the localhost IP address and not bound it to all Network interfaces it has? You really need to show your IIS config

Comment: @Andrew If I try access my api via IP instead of `localhost` I get `Invalid Hostname` responce. Exactly as request from emulator.

Comment: @Andrew I bound IIS to the localhost IP address and to `*`

Comment: As it shows the same problem locally when using an IP address as with the emulator then it is either the code of the `echo` API that is causing this (which you have not shown) or something wrong with your IIS config like you have enabled domain protection (which requires a reverse DNS lookup of the IP), it would probably be better to ask about the IIS config on https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution. Just run Proxy before run ASP NET. Important - you don't need Proxy if you build ASP NET Core project, because ASP NET Core uses Kestrel.

[image]

Comment: Sounds good that you got the solution! Congrats!